# Powershell Copy Last Modified File

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy some files from a source to a destination, however the source has multiple folders and in the folders I'd like to copy just the last file.

I can isolate the last file with the folowing:

```
gci 'D:\Data' | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 -recurse
```

It only selects the last file in the folder, so I thought a loop would do it, such as:

```
$file = gci 'D:\Data' foreach ($files in $file) { sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 | Copy-Item C:\Test\data}
```

However this keeps failing

Can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you wanting to copy the last written file in each of the subdirectories, such that 3 subdirectories would result in a copy of 3 files?

Comment: Hi, yes that’s right, last file from each directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Data -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File -Recurse | 
        Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
            Select-Object -Last 1 | 
                Copy-Item -Destination C:\Test\data
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat, just a quick question will that work through all the levels of the files till it gets to a "file"

Comment: This will get one file from each subfolder in `D:\Data`. If that subfolder contains other folders, it will still get one file only for that subfolder. If you want one file from each folder no matter how many level deep that folder is, than the code above will need a little tweak.

Comment: this works fine for what I need thanks for your help

Comment: Strange how this does not work for me. I have a folder with many files. Each file gets copied.